# Oracle SQL: Select Value From Comparing Date With Another Tables Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write ORACLE SQL but are tying myself in knots with it.  I have nothing to show.

I have a table called START_PERIOD

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 31/03/2022 |
| 2 | 01/04/2022 | 30/06/2022 |
| 3 | 01/07/2022 | 30/09/2022 |
| 4 | 01/10/2022 | 31/12/2022 |

I have a second table called APPLICATION_FORM.  The APPLICATION_FORM table holds a date field called "CS_START_DATE", plus a field called SP_ID (this value is START_PERIOD.ID ).

APPLICATION_FORM.SP_ID is assigned based on the value of APPLICATION_FORM.CS_START_DATE and this is derived from  table START_PERIOD, that is a APPLICATION_FORM.CS_START_DATE of 01/02/2022 falls between 01/01/2022 and 31/03/2022 therefore the APPLICATION_FORM.SP_ID is 1.

Unfortunately the SP_ID  and CS_START_DATE relationship has been altered and is now incorrect.

I want to use APPLICATION_FORM.CS_START_DATE and compare it against each date range within table START_PERIOD (where it falls between START_DATE AND END_DATE) and return the correct ID from table START_PERIOD.  I'll then use this ID to compare it against the APPLICATION_FORM.SP_ID to see if there is a mismatch.  In theory the APPLICATION_FORM.CS_START_DATE is always correct but the APPLICATION_FORM.SP_ID could be incorrect.

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to include sample for all involved tables, as well as the expected result. Also show us your current SQL attempt.

Comment: SELECT id FROM start_period WHERE cs_start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following SQL

```
SELECT start_period.id        AS correct_id,
       application_form.sp_id AS incorrect_id
  FROM start_period, application_form
 WHERE application_form.cs_start_date BETWEEN start_period.start_date 
                                          AND start_period.end_date
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I think I couldn't see the woods for the trees!!   Thank you